# choice() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

Tags: python

```
import random
class Environment(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locationcondition={'A': '1' , 'B': '1' }
        
self. locationcondition['A']=random.choice(0,1)
self. locationcondition['B']=random.choice(0,1)
```

Comment: You need to supply the choices in the form of a list, tuple, or other sequence, rather than separate parameters. `random.choice((0,1))`, for example.

Answer (score 1):

Hello Mirza glad you joined our community,

**Short Answer**: Pass [0, 1] as a list

```py
self. locationcondition['A']=random.choice([0,1])
self. locationcondition['B']=random.choice([0,1])
```

**Long Answer**:

in Python random.choice takes a list or set, ..etc. as an argument for example

```py
my_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a = random.choice(my_list)
print(a) # it will print random value from my_list
```

Although keep in mind that Python relies heavily on indentation
so after fixing the choice error you will encounter another error that both lines

```py
self.locationcondition['A']=random.choice(0,1)
self.locationcondition['B']=random.choice(0,1)
```

are not in the correct indentation, and they should be like this (**Corrected Code**)

```py
import random
class Environment(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.locationcondition={'A': '1' , 'B': '1' }
        
        self.locationcondition['A']=random.choice([0,1])
        self.locationcondition['B']=random.choice([0,1])
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to give `random.choice` a sequence of options.

A sequence can be something like a tuple, a list, or even a generator.

In your case you should use something like:
`random.choice((0,1))`